# Tab bar images show up in Xcode but not in app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to add new images to the tab bar items, and the images I've set show up in the storyboard editor but not in the simulator. I've tried adding different images and changing the image sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the Image field under Bar Item as well as the Selected Image. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBK5D.png).